# If the first column of file1 matches any string in file2, then replace it with the second column of file1

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have this problem and I haven't solved it... I would like to manipulate this files.. if the first column of file1 matches any string in file2, then replace it with the second column of file1... then collapse it (I mean,I need just unique values per field or "cell" in second column of the output_file)..
It doesn't matter which language solves this (awk, perl, python)... files contains 100000 lines or more... I've been trying one-line awk scripts, but nothing...

Any help appreciated.
Regards

file1.txt

```
ID100000360640  ITEM1;ITEM2  
ID100000360638  ITEM1;ITEM3  
ID100000360644  ITEM1;ITEM4  
ID100000363115  ITEM5;ITEM2;ITEM3  
ID100000363116  ITEM1;ITEM7  
ID100000382126  ITEM8;ITEM1  
ID100000002165  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM9  
ID100000002596  ITEM1;ITEM10  
ID100000003084  ITEM1
```

file2.txt

```
ID200000000419  ID100000360638;ID100000360640;ID100000360644;ID100000394921
ID200000000938 ID100000363115;ID100000363116;ID100000363117;ID100000382126  
ID200000001036  ID100000002165;ID100000398119
```

output_expected.txt

```
ID200000000419  ITEM1;ITEM3;ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM1;ITEM4;ID100000394921  
ID200000000938  ITEM5;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM1;ITEM7;ID100000363117;ITEM8;ITEM1;  
ID200000001036  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM9;ID100000398119
```

processed_output.txt

```
ID200000000419  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM4;ID100000394921  
ID200000000938  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM5;ITEM7;ITEM8;ID100000363117;  
ID200000001036  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM9;ID100000398119
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. we're not going to write your code for you, but if you show us your awk scripts, we can help you to figure out what to do to make them work.

Comment: Sure... with awk I tried but I couldn't (I'would like that)... then I tried this...  while read col1 col2; do cat file2.txt | sed -i s/$col1/$col2/g file2.txt ; done < file1.txt... but I can not "collapse"... and I think there are a lot of ways for doing this... Any help appreciated

Comment: add the above comment to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the collapsed output:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {c="";delete d;delete e;split($2, b, /;/);for (i in b)c=c";"(a[b[i]]?a[b[i]]:b[i]);split(substr(c,2),d,/;/); for(i in d)e[d[i]]=1; c=""; for (i in e){c=c";"i}; print $1,substr(c,2)}' file1.txt file2.txt
ID200000000419 ID100000394921;ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM4
ID200000000938 ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ID100000363117;ITEM5;ITEM7;ITEM8
ID200000001036 ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ID100000398119;ITEM9
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  While we are reading the first file, this creates an associative array `a` which associates the first field as a key with the second as a value.  Thus, the value of `a[ID100000360640]` is `ITEM1;ITEM2`.  This is done for all lines of `file1.txt`.  The `next` statement causes all the remaining commands to be skipped and jumps to the next line.
- `c="";delete d;delete e`

  If we have gotten here, that means that we are working on the second file, `file2.txt`.  These three commands initialize variable `c` and arrays `d` and `e` for the new line.
- `split($2, b, /;/)`

  This splits the second field on semicolons and assigns the result to array `b`.
- `for (i in b)c=c";"(a[b[i]]?a[b[i]]:b[i])`

  This creates the uncompressed output.
- `split(substr(c,2),d,/;/); for(i in d)e[d[i]]=1`

  This creates a associative array `e` whose keys are each of the fields in the uncompressed output.
- `c=""`

  This initializes `c` again to an empty line before we add to it the compressed output.
- `for (i in e)c=c";"i`

  For each key in array `e`, we add the key to string `c`.  This creates the compressed output.
- `print $1,substr(c,2)`

  This prints the complete compressed line.

Comment: For the initial uncompressed it would be easier to just use gsub `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])...`

Answer (score 1):

Through python3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open('file1.txt') as f, open('file2.txt') as r:
    d = {}
    m = f.read()
    for line in m.split('\n'):
        try:
            d.update(dict([tuple(line.split())]))
        except:
            pass
    j = r.read()
    for k in d:
        j = j.replace(k, d[k])
    print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
ID200000000419  ITEM1;ITEM3;ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM1;ITEM4;ID100000394921
ID200000000938 ITEM5;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM1;ITEM7;ID100000363117;ITEM8;ITEM1  
ID200000001036  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM9;ID100000398119
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj... so, how could I "collapse" each line to get unique ITEMs... for example something like this... ID200000000419  ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM4;ID100000394921

Comment: it's better to ask this as a new question since i already answered the question you asked.

Comment: Because you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably short awk way

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}
     {for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])
      x=split($2,b,";")
      for(i=1;i<=x;i++)y!~b[i]";"&&y=y?y";"b[i]:b[i];$2=y;y=""}1' file file2
```

---

#### Output

```
ID200000000419 ITEM1;ITEM3;ITEM2;ITEM4;ID100000394921
ID200000000938 ITEM5;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM1;ITEM7;ID100000363117;ITEM8
ID200000001036 ITEM1;ITEM2;ITEM3;ITEM9;ID100000398119
```

---

#### How it works

```
FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}
```

When the File Record Number matches total Record Number(effectively means whilst reading the first file) assign the second field to an array using the first field as a key.`Next` means skip all further instructions and go to the next record.

```
for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])
```

Now we are in the second file as FNR!=NR anymore.
For each element in the array `gsub` swaps everything that matches the key with what is contained in the array.

```
x=split($2,b,";")
```

Split the second field into array b separated by a `;`.
Assign the size of the array to x.

```
for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
```

Loop from to the size of the array.

```
y!~b[i]";"&&
```

if variable y already contains the split value in b then don't continue.

```
y=y?y";"b[i]:b[i]
```

if y exists add the value in b[i] to the end or else just set y to b[i].

```
$2=y;y=""
```

Set second field to value in y(our new string) and reset y to nothing.

---

#### Resources

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html